# How can I have no-indent in items except for new paragraph?

Tags: indentation, itemize, enumitem

I want to use `item` without indent except. I want lines after new line started with a new line.

In this example when I have a sentence after a new-line it does not start with indent. Can I force paragraphs to have a indent?

```tex
documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep,topsep=0pt,wide=0pt,nosep]
    \item I am a very long sentences. I am a very long sentences. I am a very long sentences.
    \item I am a very long sentences. I am a very long sentences. I am a very long sentences.
    I am a very long sentences. I am a very long sentences. I am a very long sentences.

    I am a very long sentences after the new line. I am a very long sentences after the new line.
    \item The end.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

output:

```
• I am a very long sentences. I am a very long sentences. I 
am a very long sentences.
• I am a very long sentences. I am a very long sentences. I 
am a very long sentences. I am a very long sentences. I am 
a very long sentences. I am a very long sentences.
I am a very long sentences after the new line.  I am a very 
long sentences after the new line. 
• The end.
```

wanted output:

```
• I am a very long sentences. I am a very long sentences. I 
am a very long sentences.
• I am a very long sentences. I am a very long sentences. I 
am a very long sentences. I am a very long sentences. I am 
a very long sentences. I am a very long sentences.
    I am a very long sentences after the new line.  I am a 
very long sentences after the new line. 
• The end.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `listparindent` key. In this example I've set it to `\parindent` which will match the rest of the document.

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}[noitemsep,topsep=0pt,wide=0pt,nosep,listparindent=\parindent]
    \item I am a very long sentences. I am a very long sentences. I am a very long sentences. 

    \item I am a very long sentences. I am a very long sentences. I am a very long sentences.
    I am a very long sentences. I am a very long sentences. I am a very long sentences.

    I am a very long sentences after the new line. I am a very long sentences after the new line.
    \item The end.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Can we do this approach also `items` in `observations`?

Comment: @alper Do you mean `description` lists? Yes it works for all `enumitem` lists.